# Ayuda con package en laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Necesito algo de ayuda para poder utilizar este packet ([picqer/php-barcode-generator](https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator)) en mi proyecto **Laravel 5**.

**Instalación**:

```
composer require picqer/php-barcode-generator
```

**Controlador**:

```
use src\BarcodeGeneratorJPG;
```

**Controlador**:

```
public function index () {
$cod_bar2 = 'F14157709998995727802010004910F139001000F19620';    
    $generatorPNG = new Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorJPG();
        $code = chr(241).$cod_bar2;
        $cod_bar2 = base64_encode( $generatorPNG->getBarcode($code, Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorJPG::TYPE_CODE_128_A));
}
```

El error que me genera laravel:

> "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorJPG' not
>   found"

Cuando cambio:

```
$generatorPNG = new Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorJPG();
```

Por este:

```
$generatorPNG = new BarcodeGeneratorJPG();
```

Me da este Error:

> "Class 'src\BarcodeGeneratorJPG' not found"

Algo me dice que debo configurar el archivo `app.php` de la carpeta `config` pero la verdad no se que debería hacer.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no encuentra la clase en la ruta que le has dado. La ruta correcta es:

```
use Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorJPG;
```

Comment: Lo siento, agregue la linea q me decías y no funciono :/

Comment: Perdón, puse la que hice yo en las pruebas. Ya he modificado la respuesta.

Comment: Lo siento me sale igual, pedro seria mucho pedir si lo subes a github para verlo ya q te funciono, Gracias.